# Node.JS FFMPEG display two videos next to each other

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

Does anyone have a clue of how to use the node.js wrapper for ffmpeg(fluent-ffmpeg) to merge two videos into one showing one on the left side and another on the right, not concatenation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a combination of filters to obtain what you want.
You first rescale the first video to the desired size for the left : https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1

`'scale=width:height'`

Then apply black bars to position the left side video ; `totalwidth` and `totalheight` are the final dimensions of the output video, `x` and `y` the positions of your rescaled-left side video : https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad-1

```
{
  filter: 'pad',
  options: 'totalwidth:totalheigth:x:y'
}
```

Finally, use the complex filter `overlay` to place your right side video ; note that it should be rescaled first : https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1

```
{
  filter: 'overlay', options: { x: 'x', y: 'y' },
},
```

Here's what your code should look like : (based on the quick documentation : https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#complexfilterfilters-map-set-complex-filtergraph)

```
ffmpeg('left_video.avi')
.input('right_video.avi')
.complexFilter([
 // Rescale input video
 'scale=width:height',

 // Add black bars to position your left video at x, y position
 {
  filter: 'pad',
  options: 'totalwidth:totalheigth:x:y'
 }

 // Overlay the second input for right side video
 {
  filter: 'overlay', options: { x: 'x', y: 'y' },
 },
], 'output');
```

Note that *i've not tested it*, but it should work

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to display 2 videos side by side.

```
ffmpeg()
.input("video1.mp4")
.input("video2.mp4")
.complexFilter([
  '[0:v]scale=300:300[0scaled]',
  '[1:v]scale=300:300[1scaled]',
  '[0scaled]pad=600:300[0padded]',
  '[0padded][1scaled]overlay=shortest=1:x=300[output]'
])
.outputOptions([
  '-map [output]'
])
.output("output.mp4")
.on("error",function(er){
  console.log("error occured: "+er.message);
})
.on("end",function(){
  console.log("success");
})
.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same result; display two videos one next to the other in one vide, in NodeJS. After some research I accomplished this by using the `exec` library (comes with Node) and a `ffmpeg` bash command from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233833/443530 .

The solution I used (worked for me):

```
let cmd = `ffmpeg -i ${pathToVid1} -i /home/shani/projects/open-app-p/files${pathToVid2} -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]' -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast ${outputFilePath}.mp4`; // one line

console.log("executing ffmpeg command... this might take a sec... ");
exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) console.log("Error ", err)
  else console.log("Done!")
})
```